Necessary and sufficient condition for a function to be measurable in completion of a measure space
During seminars on measure theory I encountered the following task: let $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ be measurable space. We will denote by $\Sigma^*$ the completion of $\Sigma$ for $\mu$. Prove, that $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ is $\Sigma^*$-measurable iff $\exists$ $\Sigma $-measurable   functions $f',f''$, such that$f'\leq f\leq f''$ and $\mu \lbrace f' \ne f''\rbrace=0$.
Here is my attempt.
First notice, that $\mathfrak B(\mathbb R)=\sigma(top(\mathbb R))$ is actually equal to $\sigma \lbrace (q,\infty)\mid q\in \mathbb Q\rbrace)$, which is not hard to prove.
$\Longleftarrow$: It is enough to show that there are some $A,C\in \Sigma$, such that $A\subseteq (f^{-1}(q,+\infty)) \subseteq C$ and $\mu(C\setminus A)=0$, which follows from equivalent characterization of $\Sigma^*$. But it is enough to take $C=f''^{-1}((q,+\infty)), A=f'^{-1}((q,+\infty))$, because of inequality $f'\leq f\leq f''$ the inclusions will . And the fact, that $\mu(C\setminus A)=0$ follows from the fact, that $\mu \lbrace f'\ne f'' \rbrace =0$ and $C\setminus A 
\subseteq \mu \lbrace f'\ne f''\rbrace$ and $C\setminus A$ is measurable.
$\Longrightarrow$: We will show the existence of these functions explicitly. For a fixed $q$ from equivalent definition of $\Sigma^*$ we find such $A_q,B_q\in \Sigma$, that $A_q\subseteq f^{-1}((q,\infty)) \subseteq B_q, \mu(B_q\setminus A_q)=0$. Define $S=\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb Q}B_q\setminus A_q$. From the sub-additivity property of the measure we get, that $\mu(S)=0$. Define $T_x=\lbrace q\in \mathbb Q: \exists B_q\setminus A_q \ x\in B_q\setminus A_q \rbrace$. Now we construct $f''$:$f''(x) =\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{ if } x\notin S \\
\sup T_x & \text{ if } x\in S
\end{cases}$. I wanted to prove, that $f''$ would satisfy the inequality and be measurable, however my proof failed. What would be the best way to proceed?

Suggestion
Try to use a decreasing sequence of sets $A_q$ and $B_q$, which could make it easier to use the supremum. Why can you always suppose this is the case?
A proof
One can always suppose the sets $A_q$ and $B_q$ to be decreasing in $q$, i.e. $A_q \subseteq A_{q'}$ whenever $q\geq q'$ and analogously for $B$. Indeed, if that were not the case choose $\tilde{A}_q = \cap_{q'\leq q} A_{q'}$ and $\tilde{B}_q = \cup_{q' \geq q} B_{q'}$, note that they are $\Sigma$ measurable and satisfy the conditions. For example, if $A_q = f^{-1}(q,\infty) \setminus Z_q$ for all $q$ then $\tilde{A}_q = f^{-1}(q,\infty) \setminus \left(\cup_{q' \leq q} Z_{q'} \right)$, and similarly if
$B_q = f^{-1}(q,\infty) \cup Z'_q$ for all $q$ then $\tilde{B}_q = f^{-1}(q,\infty) \cup \left(\cup_{q' \geq q} Z'_{q'} \right)$ where all $Z$ (and $Z'$) sets (and their countable unions) have measure $0$, from which the result is easily deduced.
Then this gives us interlocking sets
$$A_{q_1} \subseteq A_{q_2} \subseteq f^{-1}(q_2,\infty) \subseteq B_{q_2} \subseteq B_{q_3}$$
for $q_1\geq q_2\geq q_3$, where of course the $A$ and $B$ sets are $\Sigma$-measurable.
Then define $f'(x) = \sup\{q | x\in A_q\} = \sup\{q1_{A_q}(x) - \infty1_{X\setminus A_q}(x)|q\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $f''(x) = \sup\{q | x \in B_q\} = \sup\{q1_{B_q} - \infty 1_{X\setminus B_q}(x), q\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Note that then $f' \leq f \leq f''$, with equalty if $x\notin S$. Indeed, if $q\geq f(x)$ then $x\notin f^{-1}(q,\infty)$ so $x\notin A_q$ and then using that the $A_q$ are decreasing $x\notin A_{q'}$ for any $q'\geq q$ so $f'(x)\leq q$, and then necessarily $f'(x)\leq f(x)$. Similarly, if $q<f(x)$ then $x\in f^{-1}(q, \infty)$ so $x\in B_q$ and then $f''(x)\geq q$, so $f''(x)\geq f(x)$. Of course, the supremum and infimum of countable measurable functions is measurable which completes the proof.

I am sorry, but why will we have $f'\leq f\leq f''$? I tried looking for some obvious contradiction. Suppose $f''(x)<f(x)$ for some $x \in S$, that would imply, that $f(x)$ is in some $(q,\infty)$, but $f''(x)$ is not. What is the contradiction? Why can't $x$ be in some $B_p$, p<q?

You are right, I corrected the definitions of $f'$ and $f''$, and added a verification. And $A, B$ should have been decreasing sequences, not increasing sequences. I think it should work now!

Shouldn't it still be $\bigcap_{q\geq q'}B_{q'}=\widetilde B_q$? Also why $Z_q, Z_{q}'$ have measure $0$?

$Z_q$ and $Z'_{q}$ have measure $0$ due to $$\mu(Z_q)=\mu(f^{-1}(q,\infty) \setminus A_q) \leq \mu(B_q \setminus A_q) = 0.$$ The proof for $Z'_q$ is analogous.

I think both choices would work! Feel free to work with your choice of $\tilde{B}$ if you prefer. What is important is that you can suppose both sequences to be ordered, to be decreasing.

Thank you, however i should have my formulated question correctly, when asking bout $Z_q$'s: why is the difference $f^{-1}(q,\infty)\setminus A_q$ $\Sigma$-measurable, if we are only guaranteed $\Sigma$-measurability of $A_q$?

We know $A_q$ is $\Sigma$-measurable, but $f^{-1}(q,\infty)$ may not. Depending on that fact, $Z_q$ will be $\Sigma$-measurable or not; however for the completion of the measure it will have measure $0$, as it is a subset of a $\Sigma$-measurable set with measure $0$. In the proof I wrote sometimes we will need to use the measure over the completed sigma-algebra, which I still noted by $\mu$, an abuse of notation, as it is an extension of the original one.

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, and suppose we are given a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ with completion $\Sigma^*$.
Without loss of generality, assume we have:

A decreasing sequence $A_q$ such that $A_q \subseteq f^{-1}((q, \infty))$, where $A_q$ approximates $f^{-1}((q, \infty))$ from below, and
An increasing sequence $B_q$ such that $f^{-1}((q, \infty)) \subseteq B_q$, where $B_q$ approximates $f^{-1}((q, \infty))$ from above.

These sequences exist because measurable sets satisfy monotonic convergence properties, and refinements can always be constructed, but we omit these constructions here as they follow from general properties of measurable sets.

For $A_q$, as $q$ increases, the set $f^{-1}((q, \infty))$ shrinks. Thus, $A_q$ is decreasing.
For $B_q$, as $q$ decreases, the set $f^{-1}((q, \infty))$ grows. Thus, $B_q$ is increasing.

Because these are measurable sets, they are contained in $\Sigma^*$, and their limits (union for $B_q$, intersection for $A_q$) also belong to $\Sigma^*$.
Define:
$$f'(x) = \sup \{q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x \in A_q\}, \quad f''(x) = \inf \{q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x \in B_q\}.$$
Since $A_q$ is decreasing and $B_q$ is increasing, we have:
$$A_q \subseteq f^{-1}((q, \infty)) \subseteq B_q,$$
ensuring $f'(x) \leq f(x) \leq f''(x)$.

By construction, $f'$ and $f''$ are $\Sigma$-measurable because they are defined via countable intersections and unions of measurable sets.
The difference between the sequences $A_q$ and $B_q$ (and thus $f'$ and $f''$) satisfies:
$$\mu(B_q \setminus A_q) = 0.$$
Therefore, $f'(x) = f''(x)$ almost everywhere, ensuring that $f$ is squeezed between $f'$ and $f''$ and is measurable in $\Sigma^*$. Since $f'(x) \leq f(x) \leq f''(x)$ and the difference occurs only on a null set, $f$ is $\Sigma^*$-measurable.

